# how to play, next, pause, etc audio with audioservice from local file

Tags: flutter, dart, background-service

Please help me, I have a problem when I play audio from local files, if I play one file at a time, I can. and it's working. but I want like applications in general to be able to play, next, stop, etc. using a background service. the data file has been successfully displayed in the application, the data of the audio file is in the form of a LIST, while the data requested by the audioservice is in the form of a MEDIAITEM

Comment: The plugin's example already demonstrates all of those features. If you didn't know there was an example, every plugin has an example in the `example` directory. On the pub.dev page there is an example tab which shows the source code for `example/main.dart`. You can also go to GitHub to download and run the example.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to have a look on [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) package. This is meant for playing audio in background, the use case you are looking for(play,next,pause).